# Issues when using webbrowser to open multiple urls in a csv

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I've got a csv with multiple URLs that I need to check.

What I can do is automatize the opening process, so what I've done so far is:

```
import csv
import webbrowser

chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'
browser = webbrowser.get(chrome_path)

with open('urls_list.csv', 'r') as urls:
    for url in urls:
        browser.open(url)
```

The problem with this is that every url that opens it get an '%0A' added at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read lines from file then you get `\n` (new line) at the end which you have to remove.

ie.

```
url = url.strip()
```

**BTW:** `\n` in some systems has code `\x0A`, in others `\x0D` or `\x0A\x0D`